# Select documents where doc.arr[i]>n

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a collection with elements like this:

```
{
name: "Smith",
fields: [10, 20, 30]
}
```

Is there a way to select documents where second value of fields array ( fields[1]) > 15 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is:

```
 //create multikey index on field
db.test.createIndex({"fields.1" : 1})

db.test.find({"fields.1" : {$gt : 15}})
```

Comment: This can be a solution if you also include the Index on "fields.1". Can You take a look on "https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-multikey/" and maybe update your answer?

Comment: Thank you for your comment!

Comment: Just to say, is more optimized "fields.1" instead of "fields" index. Besides this, i will upvote your reply.

Comment: yes you are right! it must be {"fields.1" : 1}. Otherwise mongo will perform the full coll scan.